# I can't use a list in a UPDATE SQL

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I looked everywhere but I can't find the answer, I think it's a very simple question but I don't understand why it's not working.
I want to update value into my databasse with Sqlite3 in python.

```
            IP=[(str(self.DateIP.get_text()),
             Idutilisateur,
             str(self.NomPatient.get_text()),
             str(self.PrenomPatient.get_text()),
             str(self.Age.get_text()),
             str(self.UniteAge.get_active_text()),
             str(self.Sexe.get_active_text()),
             str(self.Poids.get_text()),
             self.Probleme.get_active()+1,
             str(self.Medoc1.get_active_text()),
             CodeUCD1[0],
             self.ATC1.get_active_text(),
             str(self.Medoc2.get_active_text()),
             CodeUCD2[0],
             self.ATC2.get_active_text(),
             self.Service.get_active()+1,
             DescriptionProbleme,
             self.Intervention.get_active()+1,
             self.Prescripteur.get_active()+1,
             self.Contact.get_active() + 1,
             self.DateMedecin.get_text(),
             self.Devenir.get_active()+1,
             self.CotationClinique.get_active()+1,
             self.CotationEconomique.get_active() + 1,
             self.CotationOrga.get_active() + 1,
             Conciliation,
             RetourMedecin
        )]


                cursor.execute(
                    "UPDATE Intervention SET DateSaisie=?, Utilisateur=?, NomPatient=?, PrenomPatient=?, AgePatient=?,UniteAgePatient=?,"
                    "SexePatient=?,Poids=?,Probleme=?,Medicament1=?,CodeUCD1=?,ATC1=?,Medicament2=?,CodeUCD2=?,ATC2=?,"
                    "Service=?,DescriptionProbleme=?,Intervention=?,Prescripteur=?,Transmission=?,DateContactMedecin=?,"
                    "DevenirIntervention=?,CotationClinique=?,CotationEconomique=?,CotationOrganisationnel=?,"
                    "Conciliation=?,JustificatifIntervention=? WHERE id=?",(IP,self.NumIP.get_text(),))
```

When i run my script I have this rollback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/charles/PycharmProjects/AnalysePharma/EcritureIP.py", line 301, in ValidationIP
cursor.execute(
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses
27, and there are 1 supplied.
```

but I HAVE 27 statement in my list IP, 
Thank you for your future answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ifind a solution, it's not a beautifull way to make it work but it's work

```
IP=[(str(self.DateIP.get_text()),
             Idutilisateur,
             str(self.NomPatient.get_text()),
             str(self.PrenomPatient.get_text()),
             str(self.Age.get_text()),
             str(self.UniteAge.get_active_text()),
             str(self.Sexe.get_active_text()),
             str(self.Poids.get_text()),
             self.Probleme.get_active()+1,
             str(self.Medoc1.get_active_text()),
             CodeUCD1[0],
             self.ATC1.get_active_text(),
             str(self.Medoc2.get_active_text()),
             CodeUCD2[0],
             self.ATC2.get_active_text(),
             self.Service.get_active()+1,
             DescriptionProbleme,
             self.Intervention.get_active()+1,
             self.Prescripteur.get_active()+1,
             self.Contact.get_active() + 1,
             self.DateMedecin.get_text(),
             self.Devenir.get_active()+1,
             self.CotationClinique.get_active()+1,
             self.CotationEconomique.get_active() + 1,
             self.CotationOrga.get_active() + 1,
             Conciliation,
             RetourMedecin
        )]
        ColonneSQL=[
            "DateSaisie",
            "Utilisateur",
            "NomPatient",
            "PrenomPatient",
            "AgePatient",
            "UniteAgePatient",
            "SexePatient",
            "Poids",
            "Probleme",
            "Medicament1",
            "CodeUCD1",
            "ATC1",
            "Medicament2",
            "CodeUCD2",
            "ATC2",
            "Service",
            "DescriptionProbleme",
            "Intervention",
            "Prescripteur",
            "Transmission",
            "DateContactMedecin",
            "DevenirIntervention",
            "CotationClinique",
            "CotationEconomique",
            "CotationOrganisationnel",
            "Conciliation",
            "JustificatifIntervention"
        ]
        nombre = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]



        #on se connecte à la base
        conn = sqlite3.connect('déclaration.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()


                for i in nombre:
                    sql = "UPDATE Intervention SET " + ColonneSQL[i] +"=? WHERE id=" + str(self.NumIP.get_text())
                    cursor.execute(sql,(IP[0][i],))
                    conn.commit()
```